# How to trim string using a search string in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have a very long string and I want to locate a specific substring in that string. For example this paragraph is a string,

`"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"`

And I have a substring `"natus"`. What I want to achieve is to cut the entire paragraph and return a string consisting the first 20 characters before `"natus"` and 20 characters after it. So from the paragraph above the output would be

```
"tis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptate"
```

How can I do this in jquery? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to write the code for it, but I would use `IndexOf` to determine the first occurance of your searched string, which will return an interger - index. On this `index` you can then do -20 and +20(+searched string length) , and use `slice()` in javascript. No need for jQuery for this.

Just check that your starting number is atleast 0 and your ending number not larger then the whole text.

Answer (score 4):

The below regex would fetch the first 20 characters and next 20 characters before and after  the string `nautus`(including nautus).

```
.*(.{20}natus.{20}).*
```

And in the replacement part give only the first captured group.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/6)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), not regexes:

```
var someText = 'your praragraph'; // this is your paragraph
var lookFor = 'natus';
var occurence = someText.indexOf(lookFor); // Here we find the first occurence
var offset = 20; // Hoe much do we want before and after
// calculate start, check if not lower than 0 (no negative values)
var start = occurence-offset < 0 ? 0 : occurence - offset ;
console.log( someText.substr(start, offset*2+lookFor.length) ); substr(start, length)
```

Why not regex? Because you should always prefer string functions above regexes in string manipulation.

And a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ydWF/2/) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first division with positive field string into two segments, and then go intercept these two segments were strings